# Form Validation over multiple Bootstrap Cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap 4 and jQuery. Currently I have a form with two (or more) BS Cards in it. Each Card contains fields for Customer Data, that should be added.

I have integrated a custom-validation, but currently I'm stucked. I not only want the colors to display the valid and the invalid fields. I also want to have a little Icon in the header of the Card, that contains an invalid form field.

In my CodePen Sample you can see the Icon already showing up. But as mentioned, this should only be the case, if there is a mistake (invalid field) in that card.

```
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();



        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ee71fca9e3.js"></script>
<form id="testForm" action="#"  method="post" class="custom-validation" novalidate>

  <div class="row p-3">

    <!-- Card 1 -->
    <div class="col-6 mb-2">

      <div class="card pax-details">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Customer 1</span>
          <span>
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body card-body-secondary collapse show">

          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">First Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="First name" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">Last Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="Last name" required />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Card 2 -->
    <div class="col-6 mb-2">

      <div class="card pax-details">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Customer 2</span>
          <span>
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body card-body-secondary collapse show">

          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">First Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="First name" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">Last Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="Last name" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="row px-3">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>    
  </div>

</form>
```

How can this be solved? Do I need an extra form for each and every Card here?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/SchweizerSchoggi/pen/OzevKy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Observations

- I've added a class hide.
- I've added id for each card.
- With those IDs I'm finding the error element and removing the class hide.
- I've put the event.preventDefault just for example to avoid an error sending that form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

          event.preventDefault(); // Rebemeber to remove this
          event.stopPropagation(); // Rebemeber to remove this
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();

          if ($('#card_body_1').find('.form-control:invalid').size() > 0) {
            $('#card_body_1').parent().children('.card-header').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').removeClass('hide');
          } else {
            $('#card_body_1').parent().children('.card-header').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').addClass('hide');
          }

          if ($('#card_body_2').find('.form-control:invalid').size() > 0) {
            $('#card_body_2').parent().children('.card-header').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').removeClass('hide');
          } else {
            $('#card_body_2').parent().children('.card-header').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').addClass('hide');
          }

        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ee71fca9e3.js"></script>
<form id="testForm" action="#" method="post" class="custom-validation" novalidate>

  <div class="row p-3">

    <!-- Card 1 -->
    <div class="col-6 mb-2">

      <div class="card pax-details">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Customer 1</span>
          <span>
            <i class="hide fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id='card_body_1' class="card-body card-body-secondary collapse show">

          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">First Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="First name" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">Last Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="Last name" required />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Card 2 -->
    <div class="col-6 mb-2">

      <div class="card pax-details">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Customer 2</span>
          <span>
            <i class="hide fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id='card_body_2' class="card-body card-body-secondary collapse show">

          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">First Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="First name" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-row">
            <label for="" class="col-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">Last Name*</label>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="" placeholder="Last name" required />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row px-3">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: That's awesome, Eleazar. Thanks for opening my eyes on this. I've never done something similiar before...  I just replaced size() with length in that jQuery line and that worked like a charm.

Comment: oh, and I added an each loop, as I don't know, how many cards will be there, they will be added dynamically.

$('.card-body').each(function () {
     if ($(this).find('.form-control:invalid').length > 0) {
            $(this).parent().children('.card-header').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').removeClass('d-none');
} else {
            $(this).parent().children('.card-header').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').addClass('d-none');
}
                    
});

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi awesome :-)